# R: read.table with quotation marks

Tags: r

I've got the following structure, saved in a txt.file:

```
" punc "
x nounsg x
" punc "
" punc "
artikel nounsg "
" punc "
```

I would like to read this txt.file into R, so I've tried this with

```
read.table("pos.txt",header=F, sep=" ")
```

but this yield in R:

```
"tpunc\t"
x\tnounsg\tx
"\tpunc\t
"\tpunc\t
artikel\tnounsg\tartikel
"\tpunc\t"
```

I would like to have a matrix with 3 columns and 6 rows instead. How could this be done?

When I add `fill = TRUE` and use `sep = "\t",` then I get:

```
 \tpunc\t             x                  \tpunc\t
 \tpunc\t             artikel            \tpunc\t
```

So there is some information lost

```
> readLines("pos.txt")[1:2]
[1] "\"\tpunc\t\""             "artikel\tnounsg\tartikel"
```

Comment: Looks like you have a tab delimiter.  Try `sep="\t"`

Comment: Then I get an error:

Comment: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 3 elements

Comment: could you upload the file in dropbox

Comment: Or at least show us the output of `readLines("pos.txt")[1:2]`.

Comment: As I can see, `read.table("pos.txt",sep="\t",quote="")` should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

```
 data <- read.table(file = "pos.txt", quote = "")
```

Quotes are set to `"` and `'` by default for `read.table`. From your question, I think you are trying to treat them as ordinary data elements. So, set the quote to empty character.

Comment: Then I've got the same problem as with fill =T and sep="\t" (see question): some information is lost

Comment: @Anita, I copied the text from your question into "pos.txt" and used this exact same statement; it worked. Maybe, if you can link the original file.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I've made a little spelling mistake with your code, that's the reason why it didn't work. Thanks!